# Filtering out of required JSON object from a JSON Array column in postgresql with the input as single parameter

Tags: postgresql

I have a select query return and it shows the result like below:

`select * from table` gives the result like below

[image]

I have parameter called `Apple` If I pass the parameter somewhere in query I should get the result like below

[image]

How to get this in postgresql. If anyone knows please share the answer below.

Comment: Sample data is better presented as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking tables.

Comment: PostgreSQL 10.10 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (GCC) 4.8.3 20140911 (Red Hat 4.8.3-9), 64-bit

Answer (score 2):

I would do this with a helper function for clarity. And it might be reusable.

```sql
create or replace function filter_jsonb_array(arr jsonb, fruit text) 
returns jsonb language sql immutable as 
$$
select coalesce
(
 (select jsonb_agg(j) from jsonb_array_elements(arr) j where j ->> 'fruit' = fruit),
 '[]'::jsonb
);
$$;
```

and then

```sql
select "Column_A", "Column_B", filter_jsonb_array("Column_JSONARRAY", 'Apple') from table_;
```

If you do not want a function then the function body can be placed directly into the select query.

```sql
select 
  "Column_A", 
  "Column_B",
  coalesce
  (
   (select jsonb_agg(j) from jsonb_array_elements("Column_JSONARRAY") j where j ->> 'fruit' = 'Apple'),
   '[]'::jsonb
  ) "Column_JSONARRAY"
 from table_;
```

Comment: i used the 2nd option which was not using functions and it was perfectly fine. But my next concern is, what i should use if the date type of fruits was a character varying [] arary?

I tried this where 'mango'=ANY(j->>'fruit') But couldnt get result properly

Comment: Try `= any((select array_agg(t) from jsonb_array_elements_text(j->'fruit') t)::text[])`. It will only work if `fruit` is an array.

Comment: Used the above. I got the answer which i expected. Any my final question is I want to use LOWER of function in  my parameter. How to do it?

Comment: I would rather lower both the parameter and the array values. So here it is. ```where lower('Mango') =  any((select array_agg(lower(t)) from jsonb_array_elements_text(j->'fruit') t)::text[])```

Comment: You are a genius. What I looked for, I completely got it. Thank you to the core

Comment: How can we use In query here. I want to find out the query results for 'Apple' and 'Mango'. What can be used to get it. Any suggestions?

Comment: `where j ->> 'fruit' = 'Apple'` becomes `where j ->> 'fruit' in ('Apple', 'Mango')`.

Comment: This is working already for varchar type values inside the JSON. What if the value insde the json is an varchar array[].  ```where lower('Mango') =  any((select array_agg(lower(t)) from jsonb_array_elements_text(j->'fruit') t)::text[])``` Here I want to use in statement to get  'Apple' along with 'Mango'. Any idea?

Comment: Then use array `&&` operator.

Comment: Remeber I am not searching inside an one sinlge Array. But I am searching from **N** number of rows. So I am not sure about using ```&&``` operator.  Can you frame the structure.

Comment: Assuming that Apple and Mango are parameters then `where array[lower('Mango'), lower('Apple')]::text[] && (select array_agg(lower(t)) from jsonb_array_elements_text(j->'fruit') t)::text[]`

Answer (score 0):

Considering your datatype of column `Column_JSONARRAY` is `JSONB`, try This:

```
with cte as (
   SELECT column_a, column_b,  (column_jsonarray ->> ( index_-1 )::int)::jsonb  AS "column_jsonarray"
     FROM table_
    CROSS JOIN jsonb_array_elements(column_jsonarray)
     WITH ORDINALITY arr(array_,index_)
    WHERE array_->>'fruit' in ('Apple') 
)

select t1.column_a, t1.column_b, jsonb_agg(t2.column_jsonarray) 
from table_ t1 
left join cte t2 on t1.column_a =t2.column_a and t1.column_b =t2.column_b

group by t1.column_a, t1.column_b
```